# variable not being set with value from querystring

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to pass a GUID variable via the query string.  When I run my game, I can see the needed variable in the querystring when it hits the page(**planetID**):

```
http://ec2.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/World_Generation/GeneratePlanet.aspx?planetID=3b757g83-f211-1236-a52c-226fw9a9f9d5
```

However, when I try to display that variable, I get this error in my browser console window(Chrome):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: planetID is not defined

Here is my code.  You can see that I am declaring the variable 'planetID' and setting it from the query string value:

```
Partial Public Class PlanetGallery
    Page.Header.DataBind()
    Public planetID As String = ""

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString("planetID")) Then planetID = Request.QueryString("planetID")

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.Page.GetType, "test", "alert('planetID from PlanetGallery_PageLoad Sub' + planetID);", True)
    End Sub

End Class
```

I'm not sure why it's not working.  I think I need another pair of eyes.

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to hear them!

Thanks!

Comment: where do you get this error? the only error you can get is a javascript error if I see correct

Comment: @jackjop thanks for asking!  I forgot to put that info in there. I've updated my question.  I get the error in my browser console window.

Comment: You're not concatenating `planetID`. You're not passing the value of your `planetID` VB variable, you're literally passing the string `"planetID"` to JavaScript.

Comment: @Santi I'm sorry, what do you mean?  planetID is just a GUID value.  Thanks!

Comment: It should be: `"alert('planetID from PlanetGallery_PageLoad Sub" & planetID & "');"` - If you want the actual value of your variable to get passed, it can't be within quotes. The javascript that you're actually passing in your example is: `alert('planetID from PlanetGallery_PageLoad Sub' + planetID);` - By passing the word planetID instead of its value, the JavaScript thinks it's a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're getting the error at browser console, you should change your code like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.Page.GetType,
      "test", "alert('planetID from PlanetGallery_PageLoad Sub" + planetID + "');", True)
```

The problem is because javascript cannot access to codebehind variables.

Your javascript is registered like this:

```
<script>
      alert("planetID from PlanetGallery_PageLoad Sub " + planetID);
</script>
```

So planetID becomes a variables this way.